# Why should I know C++ ,if I am a machine learning engineer?

Tags: machine-learning

I see there's a lot of machine learning job openings with skills requirements, **python ,R, keras,tensorflow,pytorch,spark,** etc.which are completely fine & reasonable, but why many of the recruiters include C++ ,like what is use of **C++** in ML research, or even creating ML pipelines ?

How much C++ should I know if I'm good at rest of ML skills ?

Comment: Sometimes it's simply because the company has some of its code base in C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ is often listed not because you will necessarily be coding in `C++`, but rather fundamental understanding of memory allocations, object-oriented design patterns, and other CS fundamentals that `python` (and other similar) languages abstract a bit.

Plus, there's `Cython` and other c-derivative frameworks that may be necessary to understand in a real-time environment.

Answer (score 4):

Many machine learning products emphasize on speed over accuracy, e.g. in autonomous vehicles, a model that predicts in milliseconds with 98% accuracy is more valuable than a model that predicts in seconds with 99.99% accuracy.

While Python provides many great packages for exploring machine learning research and testing proofs of concept, it is significantly slower than C++ and not acceptable for products with real-time requirements. If you want to know why Python is slower, check out this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033329/why-are-python-programs-often-slower-than-the-equivalent-program-written-in-c-or).